# Limpar Campo com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando esta função abaixo, para validar a data em todos os campos do tipo date do formulário, chamo a função no evento onBlur do txt.

```js
 function VerificaData(digData) {
            var bissexto = 0;
            var data = digData;
            var tam = data.length;
            if (tam == 10)
            {
                var dia = data.substr(0, 2);
                var mes = data.substr(3, 2);
                var ano = data.substr(6, 4);
                if ((ano > 1900) || (ano < 2100)) {
                    switch (mes)
                    {
                        case '01':
                        case '03':
                        case '05':
                        case '07':
                        case '08':
                        case '10':
                        case '12':
                            if (dia <= 31)
                            { return true; }
                            break;
                        case '04':
                        case '06':
                        case '09':
                        case '11':
                            if (dia <= 30)
                            { return true; }
                            break;
                        case '02':
                            if ((ano % 4 == 0) || (ano % 100 == 0) || (ano % 400 == 0))
                            { bissexto = 1; }
                            if ((bissexto == 1) && (dia <= 29))
                            { return true; }
                            if ((bissexto != 1) && (dia <= 28))
                            { return true; }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            alert("A Data " + data + " é inválida!");
            
            return false;
        }
```

Porém gostaria de saber como faço para que quando a data for inválida, limpar o campo ? Tentei de formar que daria certo, se fosse um txt e uma função, porém uso essa função para vários txts, então das formas que tentei, e pesquisei não funcionam.
Assim que chamo a função:

```html
onBlur="VerificaData(this.value);
```

Comment: Olá Mariana! Essa função para verificar data parece-me desnecessáriamente complexa. Podes dar exemplo de datas que ela recebe e o que pretende detectar errado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode construir outra função que interpreta o resultado da verificação da data e limpa caso não receba `true`:

```
function limparDataInvalida(campo){
     if (!VerificaData(campo.value)){
          campo.value = '';
     }
}
```

E o `onblur` passa a ficar sem o `.value`, assim:

```
<input ... onblur="limparDataInvalida(this);">
```

**Edit**

Para evitar o ciclo infinito de loops que se deve ao facto de o `alert` dentro de `VerificaData` chamar o `onblur` pode:

- Mostrar a mensagem de outra maneira que não com um `alert`, por exemplo com uma mensagem do [Jquery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Ou

- Não validar a data se ela já foi limpa e por isso está vazia, modificando o `if` para ficar assim:

  ```
  function limparDataInvalida(campo){
      //agora aqui vê primeiro se não é vazio
      if (campo.value != '' && !VerificaData(campo.value)){
          campo.value = '';
          campo.focus();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Deu certinho Isac, muito obrigado. Como eu faço para o focus ficar setado para o  campo data ? Pois ele pula para o txt de baixo. Obrigado.

Comment: Para manter o focus no campo que tem a data inválida pode fazer `campo.focus();` a seguir ao `campo.value = '';` que está dentro do `if`. Mas tenha cuidado que isso faz com que o utilizador não consiga escrever em mais nenhuma caixa da página até acertar nessa data.

Comment: Eu fiz dessa forma, só que a mensagem de alerta, entra em loop infinito.

Comment: @marianac_costa O problema é que o `alert` que está dentro de `VerificaData` força uma chamada ao `onblur`, e dai o ciclo infinito. Já coloco uma solução a isso.

Comment: muito obrigado, deu super certo, e funcionou do jeito que eu precisava.

Answer (score 3):

Mesmo que a resposta tenha sido dada pelo @Isac, eu queria deixar aqui minha contribuição.

Você pode usar uma solução completamente JavaScript, sem precisar passar nada pro HTML. Particularmente, porque eu gosto de manter tudo separado (HTML, CSS, JS, PHP, Python, Java, etc).

Você pode adicionar um [***event listener***](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) ao documento para monitorar o *blur* dos forms tipo data ou da classe que contém as valores de data, então executar sua função.

Conhecer o Document Object Model é uma forma excelente de não se perder. [***Estude-o! Você não vai se arrepender.***](https://tableless.com.br/tenha-o-dom/)

**EDIÇÃO**

**Usando somente JavaScript**

[Primeiro método, sem protótipo](https://jsfiddle.net/TonnyMontana/naqon4gx/1/):

```
// Seleciona os input tipo datanuma NodeList
var inputTipoData = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="date"]'),
    // Seleciona os input com a classe .date numa NOdeList
    inputClasseData = document.getElementsByClassName('date');

// Aplica o addEventListener para os input com tipo date
for (var i = 0; i < inputTipoData.length; i++) {
    inputTipoData[i].addEventListener('click', alertaOnBlur);
}

// Aplica o addEventListener para os input com classe date
for (var i = 0; i < inputClasseData.length; i++) {
    inputClasseData[i].addEventListener('blur', alertaOnBlur);
}
// Declara a função que será executada
function alertaOnBlur () {
    alert("Blur!!!");
};
```

[Segundo método, com protótipo](https://jsfiddle.net/TonnyMontana/kL2oL89c/):

```
// Cria um protótipo para iterar uma NodeList monitorando cada elemento com 
// addEventListener
NodeList.prototype.addEventListener = function(event, func) {
    this.forEach(function(content, item) {
       content.addEventListener(event, func);
    });
}

// Função definida por mim
function minhaFuncao () {
    alert("AAAHHHHHHH!!!");
}

// Pega todos os formulário tipo date na página
var formularioDate = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='date']");

// Monitora todos os formulários da lista acima com addEventListener
formularioDate.addEventListener("blur", minhaFuncao);
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll('input[type="date"]').addEventListener` vai dar erro, o `addEventListener` não trabalha sobre coleções como o `querySelectorAll` dá.

Comment: Perfeito, @Sergio. Muito obrigado pela correção. Vi que você já editou a resposta. Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: Tony: não editei a resposta. O erro continua lá (na tua resposta). E tens o mesmo problema em `getElementsByClassName("classe-data").addEventListener`...

Comment: E de onde saiu esse `All` então? Eu sei que `querySelectorAll` pode funcionar dentro de um loop, usado junto com addEventListener. A resposta deveria ter `querySelector` só. Erro idiota meu.

Comment: E tens o mesmo problema em `getElementsByClassName` que também retorna uma coleção.

Comment: ***Fuck!*** Dessa eu não sabia não. Vou fazer uma solução testada para essa questão. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode também, em vez de criar uma nova função, na mesma função `VerificaData(digData)` adicionar o código abaixo após o `alert`:

```
window.focus();
campos = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var x=0; x < campos.length; x++) {
  if(campos[x].value == digData) {
    campos[x].value = "";
  }
```

}

Esse código irá verificar o campo com valor enviado em `digData` e esvazia-lo.

O `window.focus();` é para tirar o `focus()` do campo para evitar que o `alert` fique infinito.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
function VerificaData(digData) {
            var bissexto = 0;
            var data = digData;
            var tam = data.length;
            if (tam == 10)
            {
                var dia = data.substr(0, 2);
                var mes = data.substr(3, 2);
                var ano = data.substr(6, 4);
                if ((ano > 1900) || (ano < 2100)) {
                    switch (mes)
                    {
                        case '01':
                        case '03':
                        case '05':
                        case '07':
                        case '08':
                        case '10':
                        case '12':
                            if (dia <= 31)
                            { return true; }
                            break;
                        case '04':
                        case '06':
                        case '09':
                        case '11':
                            if (dia <= 30)
                            { return true; }
                            break;
                        case '02':
                            if ((ano % 4 == 0) || (ano % 100 == 0) || (ano % 400 == 0))
                            { bissexto = 1; }
                            if ((bissexto == 1) && (dia <= 29))
                            { return true; }
                            if ((bissexto != 1) && (dia <= 28))
                            { return true; }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            alert("A Data " + data + " é inválida!");
            window.focus();

            campos = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var x=0; x < campos.length; x++) {
                if(campos[x].value == digData) {
                    campos[x].value = "";
                }
            }            
            return false;
        }
```